# play framework 1.2.7 ActionNotFoundException on start up

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I get a wired exception after starting a play application. The exception is thrown repeatedly.

This is what I have tried: 
- install play new. 
- run eclipsify. 
- delete and re-import the project,

but nothing helped. I did not implement the mentioned action myself. Has anybody an idea?

```
17:11:45,880 ERROR ~ 

@6h921g3i7
setwindowsagentaddrController.index action not found

Action not found
Action setwindowsagentaddrController.index could not be found. Error raised is Controller controllers.setwindowsagentaddrController not found

play.exceptions.ActionNotFoundException: Action setwindowsagentaddrController.index not found
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethod(ActionInvoker.java:599)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.resolve(ActionInvoker.java:85)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Controller controllers.setwindowsagentaddrController not found
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. Changing the port from the previous one to another with

```
http.port=9998
```

fixed the problem. I do not understand why this helped though. Maybe someone can clarify?